# Django api/signup not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Created a user registration form for my React Django app and keep getting an error even before doing anything on the form.  It keeps saying `api/signup 404 (Not Found)`.

I have added all necessary apps to my installed apps in settings.  I have also added all necessary urls as well.  For reference here are my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('articles.api.urls')),
    re_path('.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]
```

And my settings:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'c(s+3-(=_22lr86m)6km!kn&q9irg7fn$19=--wl*p=)k_bgl&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['djangoandreact.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoroot.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoroot.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'thesite'),
        'USER': 'tom',
        'PASSWORD': 'Lakers@0002!'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
SITE_ID = 1

import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

After clicking signup:

```
xhr.js:178 POST https://djangoandreact.herokuapp.com/rest-auth/registration 403 (Forbidden)
```

djangoandreact.herokuapp.com if you wanna check it out

This will work if I do it directly at https://djangoandreact.herokuapp.com/rest-auth/registration/

Comment: does it working in local machine?

Comment: can't test it as the db is in heroku

Comment: this is related to permissions. Check permissions.

Comment: I've checked all that in my settings.py.  No go

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of authentication classes:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    )
}
```